# Alternative to PHP's eval function

Tags: php, mysql, eval

I wonder if there's some alternative to the "evil" eval function for my case.

I have a "settings" form where I generate all my table's header text with PHP/MySql-code, something like:

```
$my_user_id = "somedata";
SELECT myheader FROM somewhere WHERE user = $my_user_id;
echo $my_query_result;
```

So this code is saved in the database.

And then I have a list template file where I get the code previously written to database like:

```
SELECT list_header_text FROM settings WHERE mylist = currentlist
$myheader_text = $my_query_result;
```

And then I display the text like:

```
echo eval($myheader_text);
```

I'm not sure if this is a good way to do it. And I have also a problem that I cannot get the stringlength for the code in database. When strlen is 0 I should echo a different header structure in my table header, but strlen returns the length of the code not the echoed value.

Comment: Well...this is a RAD platform where I don't want to hack the core code and to be honest, I'm noob in PHP and implementing a template engine would be too much for me.

Comment: i wonder why do you need to store php codes in db!

Comment: Because I have no idea what the good alternative would be. That's why I wrote here to get some ideas based on my current situation description.

Comment: You don't need to _implement_ a templating engine necessarily, there are plenty of existing ones you could make use of

Comment: But please kindly, as already requested, show an example of the code you are storing in the database, so we can understand precisely what you mean.

Comment: The first code snippet in my post is saved in the database. And then the code is fetched from my template's php file, eval'd and echo'd. But this snippet is always a bit different depending in which table header i need to display this. And there are several dozens of tables, so I cannot have one generic code.

Comment: Well the first snippet is not valid PHP or SQL, so nothing can execute that. I assumed that was some pseudo code example

Comment: Yes it's just a pseudo code. The actual code itself is working, so no problem there.

Comment: Save the code in a .php file, so you can simply `include()` without eval.

Comment: Thanks! I decided to go the include() way. It's much more inconvenient to handle the dozens of code snippets compared to list/form entries, but gets rid of the eval() and my another problem getting strlen of the echoed code.